how do I connect two arrays and sort only one of them in c++?
So I'm new to C++ and doing that one Buzzy's exercise with pancakes. But I have absolutely no idea how to solve the last part of it:

Modify the program so that it outputs a list in order of number of pancakes eaten of all 10 people.
i.e.
Person 4: ate 10 pancakes
Person 3: ate 7 pancakes
Person 8: ate 4 pancakes
...
Person 5: ate 0 pancakes

That's what I currently have:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int cc[10]; //the array for pancakes eaten.
    int pn[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; //"number of the person" array.

    cout << "how many pancakes they ate?\n\n";

    for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < 10 && n < 10 ; i++, n++){
        cout << "Person " << pn[n] << ": ";
        cin >> cc[i];
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < 10 && n < 10 ; i++, n++){
        cout << "person number " << pn[n] << " ate " << cc[i] << " pancakes\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

But I honestly don't know if I even think in the right direction. Very confused at this point.

Unrelated to your problem but why do you use both i and n in the loops? You only need one of them.

"doing that one Buzzy's exercise with pancakes." -- I have absolutely no idea what this is. But, fortunately, that information is not needed for your question. Just move it to the end as a contextual footnote. Keep your question more abstract: you have two arrays of related information, and you need to have that information sorted according to one of the arrays.

Searching for [c++] sort two arrays turns up: Sorting two arrays based on one with standard library (copy steps avoided) - Sorting two corresponding arrays - How to sort two arrays based on the first array - Sorting two arrays depending on the values of one array using STL -- Have you looked at any of these?

Please also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std

Bazzy’s Beginner Exercises

A simple solution is to not have two separate arrays for person numbers and the number of pancakes they ate. Create a struct holding the information about one person and the number of pancakes that person ate:
struct person {
    int number;
    int pancakes;
};

You'd then only need one array:
person persons[10];  // or  std::array<person, 10> persons;
for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(persons); ++i) persons[i].number = i + 1;

And input could use a range-based for loop:
for (auto& p : persons) {
    std::cout << "Person " << p.number << ": ";
    std::cin >> p.pancakes;
}

Similarly, output:
for (auto& p : persons) {
    std::cout << "person number " << p.number << " ate " << p.pancakes
              << " pancakes\n";
}

Now, what's missing is the actual sorting that should be done before the above printing of the result. I would recommend using std::sort with a user-defined comparison functor, like a lambda:
// lambda function:
auto comp = [](person& lhs, person& rhs) {
    return lhs.pancakes > rhs.pancakes;
};

// using std::sort with the lambda:
std::sort(std::begin(persons), std::end(persons), comp);


Using C++23, I find this solution pretty simple and elegant:
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

struct Person
{
    int index;
    int pancakeCount;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<Person, 10> people;

    std::cout << "How many pancakes did each person eat?" << std::endl;

    for (auto&& [index, person] : std::views::enumerate(people))
    {
        person.index = index + 1;
        std::cout << "Person " << person.index << ": ";
        std::cin >> person.pancakeCount;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // We use projection to sort by pancakeCount and views::reverse to sort in descending order
    std::ranges::sort(people | std::views::reverse, {}, &Person::pancakeCount);

    for (const auto& [personIndex, pancakeCount] : people)
    {
        std::cout << "Person " << personIndex << ": ate " << pancakeCount << " pancakes\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

This is similar to Ted's solution, but with some added sugar.
BTW: This works because member variables are callable.
PS: You can also do it with two arrays, but it gets unnecessarily convoluted.
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> personIndices;
    std::array<int, 10> pancakeCounts;

    std::cout << "How many pancakes did each person eat?" << std::endl;

    auto zippedIndicesAndCounts = std::views::zip(personIndices, pancakeCounts);

    for (auto&& [index, person] : std::views::enumerate(zippedIndicesAndCounts))
    {
        auto&& [personIndex, pancakeCount] = person;
        personIndex = index + 1;
        std::cout << "Person " << personIndex << ": ";
        std::cin >> pancakeCount;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::ranges::sort(zippedIndicesAndCounts | std::views::reverse, {},
                      [](const auto& element) { return std::get<1>(element); });

    for (const auto& [personIndex, pancakeCount] : zippedIndicesAndCounts)
    {
        std::cout << "Person " << personIndex << ": ate " << pancakeCount << " pancakes\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

